# libvirt can't bind device to runtime due to permission denied

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to start a new domain via libvirt `virsh start my-domain`.

But it fails with this permission denied error

```
error: internal error: Process exited prior to exec: libvirt:  error : Failed to bind /dev/my_pool/boot.raw on to /run/libvirt/qemu/1-my-domain.dev/my_pool/boot.raw: Permission denied
```

`/run/libvirt/qemu/1-my-domain.dev/my_pool/boot.raw` is a runtime file which is only created during domain start.

How can I fix this? Which permission should I fix?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the error is not permission issue. I actually used the wrong pool name in my KVM definition. The error is gone after I updated it.